# Returning JSON with Vue Router

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I need to return a JSON object when users hit /nav on my application. This JSON is used programmatically and cannot be just a string.

Is there a way to make a vue component that is only JSON? Or a way to tell the router to return JSON?

Thank you!

Comment: create a json file myinput.json and add it as input to your program.

Comment: @divine How does one "add it as an input to your program"?

Comment: @geoidesic check my answer

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem.
I wanted /nav to return JSON but only on my local development server however.

So I just created a `vue.config.js` file (in my app root folder)

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    before: function(app, server) {
      app.get('/nav', function(req, res) {
        const result = { x:1 , y : "hello" };
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

With this files when I run `npm run serve`, I get the json object when navigating to `/nav` and my regular app otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to make a vue component that is only JSON?

*Instead of creating a vue component that is only JSON, Create a JSON object and export it*

**jsonInput.js**

```
export const jsonInput = [
  { id: "1", title: "Mars" },
  { id: "2", title: "Venus" },
  { id: "3", title: "Pluto" }
];
```

*Import the JSON object into your component*

**Planets.vue**

```
<script>
    import {jsonInput } from './jsonInput';
    export default {
      data(){
          return {
              planets : jsonInput 
          }
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It would be better to share   the reason for the downvote than just downvoting

Comment: May be they downvoted because you haven't defined a template and with this code one will surely get this error : `Error: render function or template not defined in component: anonymous`

Comment: Can I serve this JSON object in a Vue Route?